# Positioning of HTML elements with css

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

### HTML Code

```
<header>
  <h1>Event Heading</h1>
  <div class="meta">09 JUL 2014</div>
  <div class="textblock">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede.</div>
</header>
```

### Issue

I have this HTML structure which I can not edit/rearrange. I would like to position the h1, div.meta and div.textblock is as in the picture below.

I can't work it out with floats the way I want to because of the sequence of the HTML.

### Illustration

[image: Trying to achieve this result]

Comment: Don't mind the actual styling of the dateblock, I'm just looking for a way to position the three elements (h1, div.meta, div.textblock) relative to each other

Comment: Did you try something on your own?

Comment: Why don't you put an extra `div` around the `h1` and `div.meta`? That makes it so much easier.

Comment: Try `h1, .textblock { float: right; } .meta { float :left; }` and work it out from there..

Comment: unfortunately I can only work with the html that is provided, I have no control about how it's generated from the system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with absolute positioning:

```
header { 
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100px; }

div.meta {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px; height:100px;
    top:0; left:0;
    border: 1px solid red; }

header h1 {
  margin-left: 120px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red; }

header div.textblock { margin-left: 120px; }
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/utsKx/

You can change the div.meta widths and h1/textblock margin-left to percentages if you want a responsive layout.

**EDIT**
Added min-height to header to ensure div.meta never falls outside the parent header block. (Thanks for MarcAudet for pointing this out)

Comment: Why use absolute positioning. This can be done easily with other means.

Comment: You might want to through a min-height value in header to make sure that the .meta element does not stick out of the parent element for very short text blocks.

Comment: @putvande I tried using floats to get a similar layout.  However, to get anything close I needed to specify widths, which is cumbersome. I would be curious to see a solution that is "done easily with other means" that do not involve absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

See this example:

[Codepen Example](http://cdpn.io/ieLJv)

I think this is what you're looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this demo

[Code Pen Demo](http://codepen.io/MariamMassadeh/pen/pBnAy)

**HTML**

```
 <header>
  <div class="meta L">09 JUL 2014</div>
  <h1 class="R">Event Heading</h1>
  <div class="textblock R">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede.</div>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
header
{
  width:650px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.meta
{
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin:5px;
  font-size:22px;
  text-align:center;
}
h1,.textblock
{
  width:400px;
  text-align:left;
  border:1px solid red;
}
h1
{
  color:#B1003B;
  margin-top:5px;
}
.textblock
{
  margin-top:-22px;
}
.L
{
  float:left;
}
.R
{
  float:right;
}
.C1
{
  color:#000000;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:36px;
}
.C2,.C3
{
  color:#777777;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
var str = $(".meta").html();
s = str.split(' ');
$(".meta").html("<span class='C1'>"+s[0]+"</span></br><span class='C2'>"+s[1]+"</span></br><span class='C3'>"+s[2]+"</span>");
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.